# Reduce function to take an undefined initial value

Tags: javascript, function, lodash

I want to create a function (reduce) that does the following:

Where:

```
var collection = [1, 2, 3];
```

and

```
function iterator(total, element) {
    return total + element;
};
```

if `initial` is defined as `3`:

```
reduce(collection, iterator, 3)
```

will do this:

```
3 + 1
4 + 2
6 + 3 = 9
```

if `initial` is `undefined`:

```
reduce(collection, iterator)
```

will do this:

```
1 + 2
3 + 3 = 6
```

Here is my code:

```
var reduce = function(collection, iterator, initial) {
    if (initial === undefined) {
        var total = 0;
    } else {
        var total = initial;
    }
    each(collection, function(element) {
        total = iterator(total, element);
    });
    return total;
}
```

It works, but you can see that I've hard-coded `total = 0`, but I want this code to work in other scenarios (for example, multiplication, where I wouldn't want 0 to make the whole product 0).

Comment: What should happen if length of array was 4 (let's say `[1,2,3,1]`) and `initial` set to 1?

Comment: Why don't you read the lodash's [`reduce`](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/blob/master/lodash.js#L6447) code?

Comment: @aduch it would be:

1+1; total = 2
2+2; total = 4
4+3; total = 7
7+1; total = 8

Comment: @thefourtheye I realize there's a method for it, but this is just a learning process that I'm going through, and I'm stuck... so it would be great if someone could help me

Comment: @HenryNg Reading and understanding others' code is an important step in the learning process.

Comment: @aduch Hmmm, I don't think so. Its the initial value for the accumulator variable.

Comment: @thefourtheye i'm not trying to discredit your comment, the reason i've resorted to asking this question is because i've already gone and read the reduce method on lodash, but i'm still stuck, so instead of spinning my wheels, i wanted to ask for help

Comment: @HenryNg Just assign the first value from `collection` to `total`, and proceed with the second element.

Comment: @thefourtheye To be fair, the lodash source code is not very a didactic study material for beginners.

Comment: @thefourtheye thanks! i set var total = collection[0] and then i removed the first element from collection via collection.shift(), and then proceeded on with each

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I would implement it:

```js
alert(reduce([1,2,3], add, 3)); // 9
alert(reduce([1,2,3], add));    // 6

function add(a, b) {
    return a + b;
}

function reduce(array, iterator, initial) {
    var length = array.length;
    var index  = 0;

    if (arguments.length < 3) {
        if (length > 0) var result = array[index++]; // Note 1
        else throw new Error("Reduce of empty array with no initial value");
    } else var result = initial;

    while (index < length) result = iterator(result, array[index++]);

    return result;
}
```

The code is pretty self explanatory. Nevertheless, here's how it works, if the number of arguments passed are less than 3 it means that `initial` was not given. Hence we set `result` to `array[0]` and increment `index`. If `array` is empty then we throw an error instead. Otherwise we set the `result` to the `initial` value passed to the function. Everything else works as normal.

**Note 1:** The reason we don't modify `initial` (i.e. write `initial = array[index++]`) is because if we use `arguments` in a function and also modify the parameters of the function then the function will [not be optimized](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/wiki/Optimization-killers#31-reassigning-a-defined-parameter-while-also-mentioning-arguments-in-the-body-typical-example) in V8. Hence, it will execute slower.

Hope this helps.